# Use an encrypted token or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, encryption, token

For API authentication based on a token: What is the advised practice:

- Save the token in the dabase encrypted or unencrypted?
- For authentication: find the user based on the token (only possible if the token is stored in the database unencrypted) or based on for example the user's email address?

I found several sources that seem to store an unencrypted token and then in authentication find the user on basis of the token received with the API request. That seems somewhat insecure to me, since then the back end searches the entire `User` table on basis of the token included in the request, irrespective which user has that token (so someone could just try out many tokens). At the same time I don't know if it it necessary to encrypt the token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd treat it as a password - encrypt it.

Then when user connects, you look up the user specified, you encrypt the provided token and compare the results for that user.

The main reason, is when you get hacked, you don't have to reset everyone's compromised tokens immediately when you restore, you should have a little more time.. as the hacker won't have access to their tokens.. and if your token is salted, may never.

Not that I'd advocate not resetting the token! Just, it's one less immediate issue in the heat of the moment.